# Quickblox API Session Creation With User & Signature Error

Tags: quickblox

**Quickblox rest api create session function running without user information but not working when I added user information.**

**Signature String:Success**

```
 string signatureStr=string.Format("application_id={0}&auth_key={1}&nonce={2}&timestamp={3}", this.application_id, this.auth_key, this.nonce, this.timestamp);
```

**Signature String:Error**

```
string signatureStr=string.Format("application_id={0}&auth_key={1}&nonce={2}&timestamp={3}&user[login]={4}&user[password]={5}", this.application_id, this.auth_key, this.nonce, this.timestamp,this.user.login,this.user.password);
```

**Generate Signature Function**

```
  public string GenerateHmacSha1(string key, string body)
    {
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);

        HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyByte);
        byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(body);
        byte[] hashMessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return ByteToString(hashMessage);
    }
```

**Error Information**

StatusCode => 422 Unprocessable Entity

Error Message=> Unexpected signature

**Why does it work?**